# How to remove black borders on embed youtube video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I need to make the video like this one here:

http://themes.laborator.co/aurum/fashion/home/home-4/?header-type=3&header-top-links=hide&header-cart-icon=5
I'm using jquery plugin. You can see here the code.

The first thing I need to do is to make height something about 550px than borders with some blur effect like in the template.

```
/*
```

jQuery backVid plugin
by Rory Standley
http://www.rstandley.co.uk
version: 1.0
licensed under the MIT License
 */

(function ($, window) {

```
    var backVid = function(node, options) {

        // Establish our default settings
        var settings = $.extend({
            ratio: 16/9, // either 4/3 or 16/9
            videoId: 'O_OKpl6u5P4',
            mute: false,
            repeat: true,
            width: $(window).width(),
            playButtonClass: 'backVid-play',
            pauseButtonClass: 'backVid-pause',
            muteButtonClass: 'backVid-mute',
            unMuteButtonClass: 'backVid-unMute',
            volumeUpClass: 'backVid-volume-up',
            volumeDownClass: 'backVid-volume-down',
            increaseVolumeBy: 10,
            mobileBackgrounType: 'colour', // either image/colour
            backgroundValue: 'rgb(0,0,0)', // either hex,RGB/Image URL - example (http://www.rstandley.co.uk/laboratory/url_shortner/UxWBHq)
            videoFilter: false, // either false/lines/bricks/squares/waves/spots/dashes/crosses
            start: 0
        }, options);

        // First we need to check to see if we have a mobile device or not
        if (checkDevice()) {
            // Now we need to append our div we will work with to the 'body'
            wrapElements();
            $('body').append(
                $('<div />').attr('id','backVid-video-player')
                            .css({
                                'position':'inherit',
                                'left':0,
                                'top': -177,
                                'overflow':'hidden',
                                'z-index':'1',
                                'height':'100%',
                                'width':'100%'
                            })
            );

            // Lets build our background value for backVid-stop-clicks
            switch(settings.videoFilter){
                case 'false':
                    myFilterBG = '0';
                    break;
                case 'lines':
                    myFilterBG = 'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAD0lEQVQImWNgQAX/yeAAAIHCA/0RE2WAAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)';
                    break;
                case 'bricks':
                    myFilterBG = 'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAE0lEQVQImWNgwAT/yRf4j0vFfwAZXgb64t36UQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)';
                    break;
                case 'squares':
                    myFilterBG = 'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAICAYAAADED76LAAAAQElEQVQYlW2OwQ0AMAgCbw7XcMFubj81RVpeGgIcQHK1gJC/+shjtkLNTmpTaZMm05IB76YzfTedaW46k28Opg1VYQ5hW3JdzwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)';
                    break;
                case 'waves':
                    myFilterBG = 'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAICAYAAADA+m62AAAAJElEQVQYlWNgwAT/sYjhVIRXMbokVsW4TPhPjCJi5clXTBwAAOy+CfekNMf3AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)';
                    break;
                case 'spots':
                    myFilterBG = 'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAAECAYAAACp8Z5+AAAAEklEQVQImWNgYGD4z0AswK4SAFXuAf8EPy+xAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)';
                    break;
                case 'dashes':
                    myFilterBG = 'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAJCAYAAADgkQYQAAAAEklEQVQYlWNgoBL4T7GCoW8FAGEXBfvNSmHvAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)';
                    break;
                case 'crosses':
                    myFilterBG = 'url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAMklEQVQYlWNgYGAwZkAFxjjEcApgSOKTIGgSVpOxKcKqmGiFRFuNUwCHGFaT8erCGuAAtV8HLQ/j6goAAAAASUVORK5CYII=)';
                    break;
                default:
                    myFilterBG = '0'
            }

            // Now we need to add a layer to stop people clicking on the YouTube video
            $('body').append(
                $('<div />').attr('id','backVid-stop-clicks')
                            .css({
                                'width':'100%',
                                'height':'100%',
                                'z-index':'2',
                                'position':'fixed',
                                'left':0,
                                'top':-177,
                                'background-image': myFilterBG
                            })
            );
        } else {
            // We have a mobile device, the auto play feature does not work, so we need to use a BG image/colour
            if (settings.mobileBackgrounType == 'image') {
                // We need to show the image url
                if (settings.backgroundValue != '') {
                    // We can assume we have a value and we must assume that it is a link to an image
                    $('body').css({
                        'background': 'url('+settings.backgroundValue+') no-repeat center center fixed',
                        '-webkit-background-size': 'cover',
                        '-moz-background-size': 'cover',
                        '-o-background-size': 'cover',
                        'background-size': 'cover',
                    });
                }
            } else if (settings.mobileBackgrounType == 'colour') {
                // We need to show a background colour
                if (settings.backgroundValue != '') {
                    // We can assume we have a value and we must assume that it is a link to an image
                    $('body').css({
                        'background': settings.backgroundValue,
                        'height':'100%',
                        'width':'100%'
                    });
                }
            }
        }


        // We are using global space in order to talk with the YouTube API
        window.player;
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
            player = new YT.Player('backVid-video-player', {
                width: settings.width,
                height: Math.ceil(settings.width / settings.ratio),
                videoId: settings.videoId,
                playerVars: {
                    controls: 0,
                    showinfo: 0,
                    modestbranding: 1,
                    wmode: 'transparent'
                },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                }
            });
        }

        window.onPlayerReady = function(e) {
            resize();
            if (settings.mute) e.target.mute();
            e.target.seekTo(settings.start);
            e.target.playVideo();
        }

        window.onPlayerStateChange = function(state) {
            if (state.data === 0 && settings.repeat) {
                player.seekTo(settings.start);
            }
        }

        // resize handler updates width, height and offset of player after resize/init
        var resize = function() {
            var width = $(window).width(),
                pWidth,
                height = $(window).height(),
                pHeight,
                $backVidPlayer = $('#backVid-video-player');

            // when screen aspect ratio differs from video, video must center and underlay one dimension

            if (width / settings.ratio < height) { // if new video height < window height (gap underneath)
                pWidth = Math.ceil(height * settings.ratio); // get new player width
                $backVidPlayer.width(pWidth).height(height).css({left: (width - pWidth) / 2, top: -117}); // player width is greater, offset left; reset top
            } else { // new video width < window width (gap to right)
                pHeight = Math.ceil(width / settings.ratio); // get new player height
                $backVidPlayer.width(width).height(pHeight).css({left: 0, top: -117}); // player height is greater, offset top; reset left
            }

        }

        $('body').on('click','.' + settings.playButtonClass, function(e) { // play button
            e.preventDefault();
            player.playVideo();
        }).on('click', '.' + settings.pauseButtonClass, function(e) { // pause button
            e.preventDefault();
            player.pauseVideo();
        }).on('click', '.' + settings.muteButtonClass, function(e) { // mute button
            e.preventDefault();
            (player.isMuted()) ? player.unMute() : player.mute();
        }).on('click', '.' + settings.volumeDownClass, function(e) { // volume down button
            e.preventDefault();
            var currentVolume = player.getVolume();
            if (currentVolume < settings.increaseVolumeBy) currentVolume = settings.increaseVolumeBy;
            player.setVolume(currentVolume - settings.increaseVolumeBy);
        }).on('click', '.' + settings.volumeUpClass, function(e) { // volume up button
            e.preventDefault();
            if (player.isMuted()) player.unMute(); // if mute is on, unmute
            var currentVolume = player.getVolume();
            if (currentVolume > 100 - settings.increaseVolumeBy) currentVolume = 100 - settings.increaseVolumeBy;
            player.setVolume(currentVolume + settings.increaseVolumeBy);
        }).on('click', '.' + settings.unMuteButtonClass, function(e) { // mute button
            e.preventDefault();
            player.unMute()
        });
    }

    // Load the YouTube API
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    // Lets create our Plugin
    $.fn.backVid = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            // First lets check to see if we have a mobile device or not
            if (!$.data(this, 'backVid_instantiated')) { // let's only run one
                $.data(this, 'backVid_instantiated',
                backVid(this, options));
            }
        });
    }

    function checkDevice() {
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
         // some code..
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function wrapElements() {
        // We are going to wrapp all the elements so we can adjust the z-index
        $('body').wrapInner($('<div />').attr('class','backVid-wrapper').css({
                'position':'relative',
                'z-index':'3'
            })
        );
    }

})(jQuery, window);
```

Comment: could you put it on plunkr? .. 
 this should work but I'm not sure would like to test it

                            .css({
                                'position':'inherit',
                                'left':0,
                                'top': -177,
                                'overflow':'hidden',
                                'z-index':'1',
                                'height':'500px',
                                'width':'100%',
                                 'border': none;
                            })

Comment: I'm don't know exactly how to work with plunkr but here is link to my site http://f-outlet.com/